# Interface errors in VS Code v1.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

Any idea what causes this interface corruption?

Tried deleting ~/.config/Code and restarting.
Tried rebuilding font cache with sudo fc-cache --force --verbose

Interface errors

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to v1.29.1 and interface is back to normal.